# Command not found when use sqoop

Tags: command, sqoop

When I use sqoop, it tells me:

> '--table: command not found'

The code is as follows:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://hadoop01:3306/result \
--username root \
--password 000000 \ 
--table stats_event \
--export-dit hdfs://hadoop01:8020/user/hive/warehouse/eclog.db/stats_event \
--input-fields-terminated-by '\t' \
--update-node allowsert \
--update-key paltform_dimension_id,date_dimension_id,event_dimension_id \
- m 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's typo mistake:
`--export-dir` and also
`--update-node allowser` --> `--update-node allowinsert`

Answer (score 1):

Typo:
`--export-dit` → `--export-dir`